# How to delete a remote branch locally after deleting the branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

In my GitHub, I have successfully merged my pull request and deleted the branch `sec1`. Then, I delete my branch locally. However, when I type `git branch -a`, I still can see the `remotes/origin/sec1` branch, like shown below

```
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/sec1
```

Then, I try `git push origin --delete sec1` but it gives me this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to https:/.../
```

Anyone can help with this?

Comment: How did you delete your branch? Is there any additional information in the error message?

Comment: Try running `git fetch --all`. `git` probably isn't aware of what happened on the remote, yet

Comment: Should the question not have to be "How do I delete a branch locally" because the remote branch has already been deleted...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: @EliranMalka unfortunately no

Comment: @BeginnerA-Z, i see. can you update the question title to reflect the content more specifically? it would benefit other users in search of your particular issue

Comment: @EliranMalka sure

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: I recommend `git fetch --prune`, but via a different route (set `fetch.prune` to `true` and then just run `git fetch`).

#### Longer

> In my GitHub, I have successfully merged my pull request and deleted the branch `sec1`.

Your subsequent `git push -d` command *would* be correct, and would work, if you had not already done the deletion.  The branch in the GitHub repository is *already gone*, and the attempt to delete it again fails *because* there's *nothing to to do!*

> Then, I delete my branch locally.

Note that *their* `sec1` is *your* `origin/sec1`; your own `sec1` is *your* `sec1`.  So you've now deleted *their* `sec1` and *your* `sec1`.

> However, when I type `git branch -a`, I still can see the `remotes/origin/sec1` branch

That's not actually a *branch*.  That's your Git's memory of their Git's branch name.  I prefer to call this a *remote-tracking name*.

There are two ways to get your Git to delete this:

- Use `git branch -r -d`: the `-d` is the delete flag, and the `-r` flag tells your Git that you're interested not in *branch* names, but rather in the *remote-tracking* names.  (The `-a` flag you're using now tells your Git that you are interested in *all* names, i.e., both branch names *and* remote-tracking names.  You can only use this with the listing options, while you can use the `-r` option for listing or for deleting.)
- Or, get your Git to scan *their* (GitHub's) branches again and see that *their* `sec1` is *gone* and therefore your Git should delete its memory of their `sec1`.

#### Details

The first one is pretty straightforward: the command

```
git branch -d -r origin/sec1
```

directs your Git to delete the remote-tracking name `origin/sec1`.  It goes away and you're done.  But it's *annoying* to have to do this a lot.

Note that you can delete any remote-tracking name at any time.  When you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

or just:

```
git fetch
```

your Git—by "your Git" I mean your Git software, working with your repository, locally on your laptop—calls up their Git (the repository and Git software over on GitHub where you cloned from).  Their Git lists out all their branch names and the commit hash IDs that go with those branch names.

Your Git now decides which of those branch names are "interesting" to you.  The default, for a normal clone, is "all of them", but you can make a so-called *single-branch* clone where your Git throws away all but one name.  Your Git then asks their Git for any *commits* they have that you don't, because the real purpose of Git is to store commits.  So they now package up any commits they have, that you don't, that you need to go along with their branch names, and send those over.  That's when you see stuff like:

```
remote: Counting objects: 100% ...
```

and:

```
Receiving objects: ...
```

and so on: at this point, your Git is getting their *commits* to add to your repository.

Once your Git has safely saved away all their commits and other supporting objects, your Git now updates *your* Git's memory of *their* Git's *branch* names.  These are your *remote-tracking names*.  Your Git simply takes each of their branch names and sticks `origin/` in front of them.

(The `origin/` part here is from the name `origin`, which is what we used when we ran `git fetch origin`.  This name is a *remote*.  You can have more than one, but `git clone` sets up the first standard remote using the name `origin`, and in many cases that's all we ever need.  So `origin` is the one you see all the time.  The remote's #1 purpose is to remember the *URL:* the `ssh://git@github.com/you/repo.git` or whatever, so that you don't have to retype it every time.)

#### Remote-tracking names are forever, or not

For some reason—probably, "by mistake", though only those who invented these things back in 2005 or so<sup>1</sup> could say for sure—whoever invented *remotes* and *remote-tracking names* decided that the way they would work by default is that your Git will have their Git list out their branch names, and then after your Git gets all their commits, your Git will *create or update* a remote-tracking name for each branch.

Well, that's fine for a while.  But *their* Git—in this case, the one over on GitHub—sometimes has branches *deleted*.  If your Git just *adds* remote-tracking names, and never *deletes* them, then at some point you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and acquire:

```
origin/hoopy-frood
origin/zaphod
```

Later, one or both of these is *gone*, but your Git never *deletes* either one.  So you—or your Git—will hang on to their branches forever, even though they don't.

You can of course delete them one by one, but wouldn't it make more sense for your Git to *notice* that, gosh, they *used* to have a `hoopy-frood` and a `zaphod`, but they don't any more?  Your Git could *automatically delete* your `origin/hoopy-frood` and `origin/zaphod` at this point.

Well, someone finally got around to putting that into Git, some time *after* the invention of remote-tracking names.  They added the `--prune` option:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```

means *call up the Git at `origin`, list out their branch names, get their commits and create or update my remote-tracking names, and oh by the way **delete the cruft too** please*.  **This ought to be the default**, but it was too late to make it the default.

Fortunately, **you can make it *your* default**.  Set the `fetch.prune` option to `true` in your Git configuration, and it becomes *your* default.  Use:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

to set this in your per-user configuration, so that it applies to *all* your repositories.  Then:

```
git fetch origin
```

will reach out to `origin`, list out their branch names, get their commits, and *clean up* too.  Running `git fetch` without specifying `origin` in particular will reach out to the appropriate remote, whatever that is,<sup>2</sup> and do the same sort of thing.

---

<sup>1</sup>Very early Git *didn't have these*.  You ran `git fetch url` every time, and then carefully picked stuff out from the mess it left behind.  Both the typing-in of URLs, and the picking-out of stuff, got boring and repetitive, and there were several competing ways to make this easier.  The method of using *remotes* and *remote-tracking names* won the popularity contest, but you can still see pieces of the various other methods if you read the `git fetch` documentation carefully.

<sup>2</sup>If you have *more than one remote*, sometimes you'll want `git fetch` to fetch from one, and sometimes you will want it to fetch from another.  Git figures out which one to use based on the *upstream* setting of the *current branch*, which is usually what you want.

If you want `git fetch` to fetch from *all* remotes, you can use `git fetch --all`.  However, it's usually better, if you want this sort of thing, to switch to using `git remote update`, which has fancier control.  It defaults to updating all remotes but lets you do all kinds of clever stuff.  See [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a remote branch, we do not use the `git branch` command - but instead `git push` with the `--delete` flag:

It should look something like this:

```
$ git push origin --delete feature/login

$ git push <name-of-remote-repository> --delete <branch-name>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remotely try this:

```
  git push -d origin <Branch-Name>
```

Locally:

```
git branch -D <Branch-Name>
```

**EDIT:**

Don´t know why my negative vote. My answer works:

[image]